# Extension of isomorphism of submodules

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ (both k-dimensional), there exists an isomorphism $L: V \to V$, where if $u \in V_1$, then $L(u) \in V_2$.

So, if now, instead of $\mathbb{F}_q$ we have a finite ring $R$, there is some condition on $R$ so the analogous for $R$-submodules of $R^{n}$ is still valid? i.e. every isomorphism of submodules of $R^{n}$ extend to an isomorphism of $R^{n}$. For instance if every submodule has a basis and every basis of a submodule can be extended to a basis of $R^{n}$ we can use the same proof in the case of the finite field, but in other case i dont know. Anyone can help me at least pointing me on the right direction about some literature? thanks

Comment: I'd say that is a very rare occurrence...

Comment: "Isomorphism of subobjects extends to isomorphism of the whole" is not the same as "exists isomorphism that takes one subobject into other subject", is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property (isomorphisms between submodules of a module extend to an automorphism of the module) is possessed by any finitely generated projective module over a [quasi-Frobenius ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring). (See *Lectures on modules and rings* by T. Y. Lam pg 415).

$R^n$ is finitely generated and projective, of course, and quasi-Frobenius rings are always Artinian, which relaxes the finiteness condition a lot.

I find myself wondering now if the condition characterizes QF rings or not... I don't know offhand.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly was i was looking for, i was expecting to that will be true for semisimple and maybe Frobenius Rings also (but i had no clue about why), but QF rings is better than expected, but makes sense cause of the Self-injectivity